# Rupee Unicode not working in R

Tags: r, string, unicode

Im trying to replace currency symbols in my corpus to text such as $ to dollar.
for eg.

```
x <- "i have \u20AC and \u0024 and \u00A3 and \u00A5 and \u20B9"
"i have € and $ and £ and ¥ and \u20b9"
```

Unicode works well for all the currency except the rupee. So what would be the problem?

my second issue is while doing a gsub, unicode replacement works for every symbol except for dollar.

```
sub('\u0024'dollar', x) ## which gives me
"i have € and $ and £ and ¥ and \u20b9dollar"
```

Replacing dollar could be done using this:

```
gsub([$], dollar, x)
```

Comment: Check [this **R** demo](https://ideone.com/A2chBq), I see different results there. I think you tried `sub('$','dollar', x)`. You need to use a literal string replacement - `gsub('$','dollar', x, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: That first issue is no real issue, it is just how the Unicode symbols are displayed in RGui. Regarding `gsub([$], dollar, x)`, there is no need to use a regex. Use what I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: So does that mean there no way to show rupee symbol in R. Also when the unicode gsub works for all the other currency, then why not for rupee.

Comment: It works - `sub('\u20b9','rupee', x, fixed=TRUE)` -> `[1] "i have € and $ and £ and ¥ and rupee"`

Comment: Does `cat(x)` solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it does so it must be a gui issue. But why am i not able to replace dollar using unicode?

Comment: You can replace a dollar sign, but when you do not pass `fixed=TRUE`, `sub` and `gsub` parses the `"$"` as a regex pattern, and in regex, `$` denotes the end of string. That is why in your results, `dollar` is added after the rupee.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. But my question is i can replace euros and other currency using unicode but not dollar, why that anomaly?

Comment: I explained it. The `$` symbol in regex is a zero-width assertion matching the end of string. It is not at all related to Unicode.

Comment: Also, note that `sub('\u20AC','dollar', x)` replaces a *euro* sign and the result is `"i have dollar and $ and £ and ¥ and  ₹"`. You did not even try to replace a `$` with that line of code.

Comment: Sorry for that i tried replacing a dollar sign it self and got this as an ouput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view your `x` with the rupee in it, use [`cat`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html):

```
> cat(x, sep="\n")
i have € and $ and £ and ¥ and ₹
>
```

To replace the dollar, use a literal string replacement by adding `fixed=TRUE` (so as not to escape the `$` symbol that denotes the end of string in a regex):

```
> x <- gsub("$", "dollar", x, fixed=TRUE)
> cat(x, sep="\n")
i have € and dollar and £ and ¥ and ₹
>
```

When you do not pass `fixed=TRUE`, `sub` and `gsub` parses the `"$"` as a regex pattern, and in regex, `$` denotes the end of string. That is why in your results, `dollar` is added after the rupee.